# ASP.NET MVC - Cant get to my controller index page (or any other)

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, controller

Ok so i got a 'web' that keeps track of books in a bookstore.

I have HomeController and BookController. I havent changed anything in RouteConfig,
nor did i touch HomeController. When i run my website (F5) it takes me to http://localhost:44328/
aka (Views > Home > ) Index.cshtml which is all right.

BUT, when i add /Book to my URL it still stays on the index.cshtml (HomeController).
I also tried with /Book/Index in url but it gives me 404 error. Even though i do have my index.cshtml in Views > Book folder.

```
//My BookController actions:

    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AddForm()
    {

        BookGenreViewModel vm = new BookGenreViewModel();
        vm.Genres = DAL.DALGenre.GetAll();
        return View(vm);
       
    }
public ActionResult List()
        {
            List<Book> books = DAL.DALBook.GetAll();
            return View(books);
        }
```

Not sure if i understand this routing or whatever it is.

Anything i should know?

EDIT: when i manually go localhost:port/Book/Book it works.

Comment: Do you have the BookController into the Controllers folder? and do you have the Index.cshtml into the /Views/Book folder

Comment: @Julián Yes, and yes. Both are where they need to be. I have Index, AddForm and List cshtml files in my Views > Book folder yet none of these actions work properly when i manually access them with URL

Comment: @Julián just realized when i manually go localhost:port/Book/Book/index.html 
 it works.

Comment: If you add another controller and view, do you have the same problem?

Comment: @Julián I implemented TestController with the same code as in BookController. Added all the view pages to actions (copy paste from Book views to Test views). It works. When i manually went localhost:port/Test it led me to my index action/page no problem.

Comment: hmmm, the book view is empty? and if you delete and recreate the book controller and view?

Comment: @Julián Book view wasnt empty. It had all the views for controller's actions it needs. I didnt check as far as re-creating go , since i got the result i wanted by TestController/View i made which was identical to BookController/View